# Why my three dimensions array is getting so slow when I assign another array to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

Why my three dimensions array is getting so slow when I assign another array to it?

SerializableQuaternion is a custom type for saving, so it's different from Quaternion.

Is there a better way to increase the copy performance?

```
var anro = Quaternion[60,60,60]; //216000 element
Rotate = new SerializableQuaternion[anro.GetLength(0), anro.GetLength(1), anro.GetLength(2)];
        if (anro != null)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < anro.GetLength(0); a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < anro.GetLength(1); b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < anro.GetLength(2); c++)
                    {
                        Rotate[a, b, c] = anro[a, b, c];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

or how make the array.copy can copy the different version types?

```
my custom type

[System.Serializable]
public struct SerializableQuaternion
{
    public float x;

    public float y;

    public float z;

    public float w;

    public SerializableQuaternion(float rX, float rY, float rZ, float rW)
    {
        x = rX;
        y = rY;
        z = rZ;
        w = rW;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}]", x, y, z, w);
    }

    public static implicit operator Quaternion(SerializableQuaternion rValue)
    {
        return new Quaternion(rValue.x, rValue.y, rValue.z, rValue.w);
    }

    public static implicit operator SerializableQuaternion(Quaternion rValue)
    {
        return new SerializableQuaternion(rValue.x, rValue.y, rValue.z, rValue.w);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you not considered just doing Array.Copy ?

Comment: @BugFinder It is two different types though ... `Quaternion` vs `SerializableQuaternion` .. => What you will get is `ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested and it takes about `11ms` which isn't actually that slow in my eyes - depends of course how often you have to do this.

However,

- `Array.Copy` **would** be fast but the main issue is that `Quaternion` and `SerializableQuaternion` are different types so you can not use it.
- You can also not use `Buffer.BlockCopy` since the types are not primitives (`float`, `int`, etc).

But what you can do is using [`Marhsal.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy).

For this to work you have to know your how your structs are layed out in bytes  which luckily we happen to know from the [Source Code of `Quaternion`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Quaternion.cs)

> ```
> [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
> [Unity.IL2CPP.CompilerServices.Il2CppEagerStaticClassConstruction]
> public partial struct Quaternion : IEquatable<Quaternion>, IFormattable
> {
>     // X component of the Quaternion. Don't modify this directly unless you know quaternions inside out.
>     public float x;
>     // Y component of the Quaternion. Don't modify this directly unless you know quaternions inside out.
>     public float y;
>     // Z component of the Quaternion. Don't modify this directly unless you know quaternions inside out.
>     public float z;
>     // W component of the Quaternion. Don't modify this directly unless you know quaternions inside out.
>     public float w;
>     ....
> ```

so you only need to make sure that your type looks exactly the same byte wise (which seems already the case).

Now I am no marshal expert so there might even be a more direct way of doing this but you could have an in between step converting the `Quternion[,,]` to `byte[]` and from there to `SerializableQuaternion[,,]` like e.g.

```
private static void MarshalCopy<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom[,,] source, TTo[,,] destination) where TFrom : struct where TTo : struct
{
    if (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TFrom)) != Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TTo)))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{typeof(TFrom).AssemblyQualifiedName} can not by marshaled into {typeof(TTo).AssemblyQualifiedName}");
    }

    var sourceHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(source, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    var destinationHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(destination, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        var sourcePointer = sourceHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        var bytes = new byte[source.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TFrom))];
        Marshal.Copy(sourcePointer, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        var destinationPointer = destinationHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, destinationPointer, bytes.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sourceHandle.IsAllocated)
            sourceHandle.Free();

        if (destinationHandle.IsAllocated)
            destinationHandle.Free();
    }
}
```

and a little demo

```
var origin = new Quaternion[60, 60, 60];
for (var a = 0; a < origin.GetLength(0); a++)
{
    for (var b = 0; b < origin.GetLength(1); b++)
    {
        for (var c = 0; c < origin.GetLength(2); c++)
        {
            origin[a, b, c] = Quaternion.Euler(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-360f, 360f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-360f, 360f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(-360f, 360f));
        }
    }
}

var target = new SerializableQuaternion[origin.GetLength(0), origin.GetLength(1), origin.GetLength(2)];
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Restart();

for (var a = 0; a < origin.GetLength(0); a++)
{
    for (var b = 0; b < origin.GetLength(1); b++)
    {
        for (var c = 0; c < origin.GetLength(2); c++)
        {
            target[a, b, c] = origin[a, b, c];
        }
    }
}

sw.Stop();
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Your way: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

sw.Restart();

var target2 = new SerializableQuaternion[origin.GetLength(0), origin.GetLength(1), origin.GetLength(2)];
MarshalCopy(origin, target2);

sw.Stop();
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Alternative way: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");

for (var a = 0; a < origin.GetLength(0); a++)
{
    for (var b = 0; b < origin.GetLength(1); b++)
    {
        for (var c = 0; c < origin.GetLength(2); c++)
        {
            if ((Quaternion)target2[a, b, c] != target[a, b, c])
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Oh no error in copy!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

=>

```
Your way: 12ms
Alternative way: 1ms
```

and from another test run with `600, 60, 60`

```
Your way: 123ms
Alternative way: 12ms
```

so I think we can say mine is faster by a factor of `10` ;)

Comment: thank i also test "AnimateRotate = new SerializableQuaternion[anro.GetLength(0), anro.GetLength(1), anro.GetLength(2)];"  This is using too much memory  10M it slow down performance

Comment: @stingalimiangalimian well there won't be really a way around that ... the question is: What do you even need this for? You could also directly serialize to `byte[]` and get rid of the `SerializableQuaternion` if it is just for storing and reading it